# Are they equally stored in memory in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, cpython

As we know that Python3 takes all string characters as Unicode code point.

```
type('\x0d')
<class 'str'>
type(b'\x0d')
<class 'bytes'>
```

The ascii of `b'\x0d'` is `13`,stored in memory in the form of `0000 0111`,`'\x0d'` is stored in the same format of `0000 0111` or not?Are they equally stored in memory?
To dig more to make me more confused:

```
#My python version
python3 --version
Python 3.9.2
#in python cli
len(b'\x0d')
1
import sys
print(sys.getsizeof(b'\x0d'))
34
```

`b\x0d` is not stored in the form of `00000111` in memory?

```
print(sys.getsizeof('\x0d'))
50
```

From using `sys.getsizeof` make me understand that:

1. `string` and `bytes` are stored with different objects in python3.
2. When we say that `b\x0d` is stored in the form of `00000111` in memory,it is based on some abstract level,in fact `b\x0d` is stored with 34 bytes in pc's memory for cython3?

Comment: You need to be rather more specific here. Why does it matter? They're not comparable. You need to `encode` or `decode` one of them to make them comparable. The underlying data structures that store them are implementation details, so even if on some interpreters they mostly look the same, that has no bearing on what the language guarantees (which is essentially nothing; text types and bytes-like types are almost unrelated by the spec, aside from both being sequence types and have a similar set of APIs for historical reasons). What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: The amount of memory used by a string will depend on your version of Python and the contents of the string. 3.0 and 3.9 are very different.  A byte string will be more consistent.

Comment: Python strings are sequences of unicode code points. Exactly how they're represented in memory is an implementation detail. If you want to ask about CPython implementation details, you should tag this question `cpython`.

Comment: I updated my question after more googling with your provided key words,and make it more deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the memory contents of each object in CPython if you are curious.  The size of the object can be queried by `sys.getsizeof(obj)` and the memory address happens to be the `id(obj)` of the object in the current implementation.  The `ctypes` module has a `string_at` function that takes a memory address and size to read memory:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> import ctypes
>>> x = '\x0d'
>>> ctypes.string_at(id(x), sys.getsizeof(x)).hex()
'02ca9a3b0000000070a427b3fb7f00000100000000000000c879dc5ef7a24b87e40000000000000000000000000000000d00'
>>> x = b'\x0d'
>>> ctypes.string_at(id(x), sys.getsizeof(x)).hex()
'01ca9a3b00000000b0b126b3fb7f00000100000000000000c879dc5ef7a24b870d00'
```

Above you can see the objects have a different memory image, but in this case, at least, the data in the object is stored in the last bytes `0d 00` and is identical due to CPython using the `latin-1` 8-bit encoding to store the Unicode string (see [PEP 393](https://peps.python.org/pep-0393/) for details).  CPython adds a null terminator as another implementation detail.  The other bytes represent data in the implementation of the `PyBytes` and `PyUnicode` objects in CPython.

Comment: As an additional level of implementation detail, the number of bytes taken by each character of a `str` will vary in the latest versions of Python.  It will depend on the largest codepoint contained within the string.  A single emoji can quadruple the memory taken by the string.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, I was just adding a reference to PEP 393 that explains that.

Comment: Good on you for knowing which PEP it is, I couldn't have told you.

Comment: Note that this test will not work on any type with separately allocated storage (among other things, `str` itself can store its string data in up to two other forms, separately allocated, generated on demand when accessed by specific C APIs); in that case `sys.getsizeof` will report the additional size, but since the data isn't contiguous, `ctypes` will just show random garbage out or other objects out beyond the end of the contiguous data (or crash your program if you're unlucky).

Answer (score 1):

CPython currently encodes (text) strings using the minimum of 8,16, 32 bits per character (in LATIN-1, UTF-16(?), UTF-32) to fit all characters contained in the string.

So, if all of your characters fit in the LATIN-1 encoding - which feature a 1:1 matching with unicode codepoints <256, it will use only one byte per character internally.

I've seem somewhere (sorry, it was a debate in comments in a question here, but I can´t find it now) there are future plans to keep text-strings utf-8 encoded in memory, so to avoid a large overhead in the great majority of text-related workflows, where a utf-8 byte string is decoded to the internal representation to be little used. Pypy currently uses that approach.

Comment: I thought they didn't want to use variable-length encoding for internal storage of strings due to the difficulty of indexing to a character.  What changed their mind?

Comment: it is dificult, byt not impossible - to have parallel data structures which allow indexing the characters linearly, even in a text containing characters that take more than 1 byte in utf-8. 
The fact pypy does it, and some other languages, show it is posible, The fact it's nof been done yet, show it is not trivial :-). Very likely, even such an implementation will have a fallback for internal utf-32 for certain workloads.

Comment: Strings being immutable makes that a more workable solution than if they weren't, but it will still be awkward.